# Blazor WASM AAD auth always returns to homepage

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have my Blazor WASM site set up with Azure AD Authentication, and it works great. However, if I am sent to authenticate from any page that is not the homepage (for example mysite.com/counter), when the auth is successful I am redirected to the homepage (mysite.com) I assume there is some state that I can save client side of where the user was before the user was redirected for authentication but I cannot find it.

Edit: I Did some more digging and realized that if a user already has sign in before and is coming back to the site with a page link (for example: mysite.com/counter), it works no problem. However, if a user has not authenticated and it is sent to the login.microsoftonline.com by the authorize attribute of my page the redirect url that is sent is the mysite.com/authentication/login-callback instead of the mysite.com/counter

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RedirectToLogin` component, it preserves the current URL that the user is attempting to access so that they can be returned to that page if authentication is successful.

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo(
            $"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}");
    }
}
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-5.0#redirecttologin-component

Comment: I am do have that, I have done a bit more digging, and if a user already has sign in before and is coming back to the site, it works no problem. However, if a user has not authenticated and it is sent to the login.microsoftonline.com by the authorize attribute of my page the redirect url that is sent is the mysite.com/authentication/login-callback instead of the mysite.com/couter